# Distinct Count in Pivot in Excel 2010

Tags: excel, pivot

There is a feature of "Distinct Count" in 2013 excel pivot, but thrs no such option in 2010 excel...is thr any alternative? pl help...I want distinct count of names with country pulled to rows and quaretr pulled to columns in the pivot, given below is an example[image]

Result should be Distinct count of Names for India for Q1 is 2 (2 times Rajesh and Ramesh once)

Comment: Have a look here: [Pivot Table - Count unique values - Excel 2010](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18898138/pivot-table-count-unique-values-excel-2010)

Comment: Those solutions are asking to insert a formula, which I already did and that's getting the sheet stuck. I need a solution that takes less help of processor, as I have around 1 lakh to 2 lakh rows