# Distinct Count Duplicate Value

Tags: excel, vba, count, distinct

I need help for distinct count for duplicate value and output required as follows.

If Column A's value is 28 the result should be `unique1(Column E)` Else if Column A's value is 29 then the result should be `Column F(Unique2)`

```
Code    Product     Quantity    Weight  Unique1 Unique2
28      Apple       9           100     1       0
28      Orange      9           100     1       0
28      Apple       9           100     0       0
29      Apple       9           200     0       1
29      Apple       10          100     0       1
29      Apple       10          100     0       0
28      Orange      9           200     1       0
```

I tried *Mr.tigeravatar* code and it is working fine, but I don't know how to add an `if ... else` condition for checking and output in a different column.

Comment: Should be easy enough - `IF(Column A=28,Column E, IF(Column A=29, Column F, Col To Return if Neither))`  or you could use `CHOOSE(Column A - 27, Column E, Column F)`

Comment: re: *'I tried Mr.tigeravatar code'* Cool. Which code is that?

Comment: Sorry Sir I am unable to post the full code due limitation. But I search in google and search result link is https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32125625/unique-count-formula-for-large-dataset and tigeravatar code is found

Answer (score 0):

For validation try this code: paste it in cell G2 or whatever preceding columns in row 2.

```
=IF(OR(AND(A2=28,E2=1,F2<>1),AND(A2=29,E2<>1,F2=1)),"Correct","Incorrect")
```