# Creating Calculated Field with SUM and COUNT of Fields Pivot Table

Tags: excel-2010, pivot-table, calculated-columns

Here's a snapshot of my pivot table.

[image]

I want to create a calculated field that displays the percentage from the 
**Responded** column (C) over the **Ticket #** column (B) as in column G.

The **Ticket #** column is a column of value text strings (e.g. 413456, 464313) and the **Responded** column is a list of 1's and 0's. In my pivot table I am taking the count of all Ticket # and the sum of the Responded.

I tried to create a calculated field with the following formula

```
=Responded/COUNT('Ticket #')
```

but this gave me the same as **Sum of Responded**. How can I create a calculated field that gives me the % in column G?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From my experience and what another SO member posted, `COUNT` doesn't seem to work well in pivot table field calculations. I managed to count the distinct tickets by creating a helper column of 1's and 0's in my data source. (Thanks to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11876238/simple-pivot-table-to-count-unique-values) response from Siddarth Rout.)

Once you have 1's associated with each distinct tickets, I simply created the calculated with `Responded/Ticket #`.

Comment: I wanted a simple `COUNT` calculation which could be used in other calculations (i.e.: `SUM(Field_1)/RowCount`.  What worked best is to add a field to the source Excel Table called 'Records' with a numeric value '1' for every record; Then the Pivot Field Calculation is `SUM(Field_1) /Records`.