# Excel pivot table "Count of"; calculate for 80

Tags: excel, count, pivot

I have a list of items :

"Partner"

```
A
A
B
B
B
C
```

I create a Pivot table over these, to counf of many occurrences I have of A, B and C.
The result:

```
"Row label"  "Count of Partner"

A            2
B            3
C            1
```

Now, I would like to have a calculation based on the "Count of Partner"

> = "Amount" = "Count of Partner"*80

```
"Row label"  "Count of Partner" "Amount"
A            2                  160
B            3                  240
C            1                  80
```

It seems simple... but, I don't really find a solution.
I could for sure copy do the calculation out of the pivot table, but I would loose the dynamic of data.

Can you please help?

Thank you,

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Creating Calculated Field with SUM and COUNT of Fields Pivot Table](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38361835/11683)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this my adding a new measure to the range.
just right  click on range and add measure. Mention the formula as [Count of Partner]*80
refer the image below

[image]

Answer (score 0):

thank you!
I had to look a bit, as this option is not available with the normal Pivot Table version.
I had to activate the "Power Pitot" Option.