# How to sum data related to distinct values in pivot table

Tags: excel, pivot

[image]

The batch id is unique identifier for a batch

Comment: I think your answer is already [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11876238/simple-pivot-table-to-count-unique-values)

Comment: The version is excel 13