# Comparing excel cell pairs in a column for matches or differences in another column

Tags: excel, if-statement, for-loop

My data consists of two columns of interest, A & B.

Each unique cell should have the same corresponding serial number i.e. each entry for `KR0146U09A3` should have the same serial number which it does `B150501388`, I am happy to drop the `A08` and `A09` part of the string. Similarly `KR0146U21A1` entries both have `0000a000K2008438a` as it's serial number.

I am comfortable constructing if statements in excel for string matching but I can't understand how to construct the for loop to loop down through the list for each cell pair.

I guess the pseudocode for the task is: for each unique cell in column A check if the corresponding cells in B are the same.

Can someone provide me with a start as to how I could write a function to do this in excel?

Below is an example of my data:

```
Cell        Serial Number
KR0146U09A3 B150501388-A08
KR0146U09A3 B150501388-A09
KR0146U09A3 B150501388-A08
KR0146U09A3 B150501388-A09
KR0146U09B3 B150501395-A08
KR0146U09B3 B150501395-A08
KR0146U09B3 B150501395-A09
KR0146U09B3 B150501395-A09
KR0146U09C3 B150501391-A08
KR0146U09C3 B150501391-A08
KR0146U09C3 B150501391-A09
KR0146U09C3 B150501391-A09
KR0146U21A1 0000a000K2008438a
KR0146U21A1 0000a000K2008438a
KR0146U21A2 0000a000K2008438a
KR0146U21A2 0000a000K2008438a
KR0146U21A3 0000a000K2008438a
KR0146U21A3 0000a000K2008438a
KR0146U21B1 0000a000K2008447a
KR0146U21B1 0000a000K2008447a
KR0146U21B2 0000a000K2008447a
KR0146U21B2 0000a000K2008447a
KR0146U21B3 0000a000K2008447a
KR0146U21B3 0000a000K2008447a
KR0146U21C1 0000a000K2008404a
KR0146U21C1 0000a000K2008404a
KR0146U21C2 0000a000K2008404a
KR0146U21C2 0000a000K2008404a
KR0146U21C3 0000a000K2008404a
KR0146U21C3 0000a000K2008404a
```

Comment: Add a helper column with your truncated serial number, then use `COUNTIFS` to get the count of where the cells and truncated serial numbers match, and compare that to a `COUNTIF` of the number of Cells of the type.  If the Counts are the same, they all match, if not, they don't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Expanding on my comment: Add a helper column with your truncated serial number, then use COUNTIFS to get the count of where the cells and truncated serial numbers match, and compare that to a COUNTIF of the number of Cells of the type. If the Counts are the same, they all match, if not, they don't.

### Formula:

```
=COUNTIF(Cell,A2)=COUNTIFS(Cell,A2,TruncatedSN,D2)
```

**EDIT:** *you can use this formula for the truncation*

```
=IFERROR(LEFT(B2,FIND("-",B2)),B2)
```

Where `Cell` and `TruncatedSN` refer to the so-labelled columns below.

You can see where I changed the entry in `B8` so as to cause a mismatch:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Copy your `Serial Number` column and parse that copied column with Text to Columns and `-` as the delimiter. Then pivot all the data within a Data Model with `Cell` for ROWS and Distinct Count of Serial Number2 for Values. Anything other than `1` would indicate a `Cell` with more than one `Serial Number`.

If you do not have Distinct Count, insert a PivotTable anyway with `Cell` above Serial Number2 for ROWS and Count of Serial Number2 for VALUES.  Choose Show in Tabular Form for Report Layout and do not subtotal. In Field Settings... for `Cell` do not check Repeat item labels. Blanks in the `Cells` column should indicate where associated Serial Numbers are not unique for the `Cell` value.

Comment: Here's a link to a thread with screenshots showing how to enable `Distinct Count`  [Simple Pivot Table to Count Unique Values](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11876238/simple-pivot-table-to-count-unique-values)

Comment: Guys thank you both for responding to my post, I'm very grateful.