# Understanding Pivot Table Count

Tags: excel, excel-formula, pivot-table

I was analyzing some data using Pivot Tables and noticed something strange.

I am attaching below the screenshots for details.

`The first image if of the data, I have filtered it for a particular Brewery`

[image]

`The second image is of the rows and values selected in Pivot table`

[image]

`And the third image is of the analysis spit out by excel.`

[image]

My question is shouldn't the `count` of `category` for '(512) Brewing Company`be`4` which is the distinct values of category as seen from the second image?

If not then how come I can get the unique count of categories using the pivot table.?

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Simple Pivot Table to Count Unique Values](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11876238/simple-pivot-table-to-count-unique-values)

Comment: Only (Rows) and (Columns) Field show Unque values. If you put Category in Values box, it will still show total count for all (512) Brewing Company.

What you can do is - Put one more Category in Column box. Or let me know if you have something else to do.

Answer (score 0):

one way of doing it is to pull the category field just below Brewery one while keeping Category also in the values

This will help you to have the count you are looking for, one thing that may bother you are th subtotals that will appear for each Brewery, but this can be easy fixed by right clicking on them and select "Remove Subtotal..."

Hope this helps, if not let me know

Kind regards