# How to create calculated column in excel pivot table?

Tags: excel, pivot-table, excel-pivot

I have 3 columns in my excel sheet - ID, Version, Material No.

for ex -

[image]

and i want the pivot table to be like -

[image]

How can i create the third calculated column because it involves two aggregation function to create it.
I am looking for count of maximum version so i need MAX function also, not count of unique values.

Comment: Could you explain the calculation logic for third column?

Comment: For one particular ID (say 1) the third column should calculate the count of material no which has maximum version. For ID 1 highest version is 2 and only material no 101 is there. So third column should be 1. Similarly for ID 2 max Version is 2 and 3 material (103,104,105) has these version so third columns should have value as 3.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Simple Pivot Table to Count Unique Values](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11876238/simple-pivot-table-to-count-unique-values) . If I understand your description correct.

Comment: No Sir, this is not exact duplicate of that. Thanks for your suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

Consider a solution based on worksheet functions.

Assuming the table is in  `B5:D14`,
enter an array formula, which counts unique IDs

```
=SUM(N($B$5:$B$14<>$B$4:$B$13))
```

into `G2`, enter

```
COUNT($B$5:$B$14)-G2
```

in `H2`.

Enter an array formula (
type <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>
instead of just <kbd>Enter</kbd>),
which collects unique IDs on top and fill the rest of the output lines with blanks:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($B$1:$B$14,SMALL(N($B$5:$B$14<>$B$4:$B$13)*ROW($B$5:$B$14),ROW(B5)-ROW($B$4)+$H$2))*N(SMALL(N($B$5:$B$14<>$B$4:$B$13)*ROW($B$5:$B$14),ROW(B5)-ROW($B$4)+$H$2)>0),"")
```

in `G5`, another array formula

```
=IF(LEN(G5)>0,MAX(N($B$5:$B$14=G5)*$C$5:$C$14),"")
```

in `H5` and one more array formula

```
=IF(LEN(G5)>0,SUM(($B$5:$B$14=G5)*($C$5:$C$14=H5)),"")
```

in `I5`, select range `G5:I5` and drag/copy it down.

[image]