# Excel count number of days by group

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a table with employee ID and benefits receive date as below.

The first column is ID and the second column is the date

```
Employee ID Date
1   01/01/2013
1   01/10/2013
1   11/01/2013
2   03/01/2014
2   04/01/2014
2   05/10/2014
3   03/01/2016
3   04/01/2016
3   06/01/2016
3   08/01/2016
```

I need to find an automated way to calculate the number of days has each employee receive the benefit. For example, employee #1 is 305 days (11/1/2013 - 1/1/2013 + 1). The result should look like this:

```
Employee ID Days
1        305
2        71
3        154
```

I have tried to use "if" and "sumproduct" function discussed here: [Simple Pivot Table to Count Unique Values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11876238/simple-pivot-table-to-count-unique-values)
and that does not get the answer I am looking for.

Comment: What do you get from Pivot Table?

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
=MAX(IF(A:A=E2;B:B;""))-MIN(IF(A:A=E2;B:B;""))+1
```

accept formula <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd>

A - column with employee id 
B - column with date
E2 - cell with employee id