# How to calculate average of parent category in excel?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, pivot

I have data in below format. It shows starting and end time of an activity and calculates duration accordingly. The activity is performed through out the day at different times.

[image]

I have added a pivot. I want to find out the average duration in a workday or a holiday(Day category). When I am trying to apply average in the current pivot, it is dividing the total duration by the number of sessions in a day.For example in week 1, an activity was done on 4 work days and the total duration for the activity in workdays was 04.19, I want to divide this number by 4 and find out the average time spent on each day but the pivot divides it by 11 which is the total number of sessions in the four days.

[image]

[Link for data](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1UfvWRdvba4wLAt9UDGk9ewC-2GPfjrStUzbQgL-s36k/edit?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Steps:

1. Add a helper column to identify how many unique pairs of Dates/Day Categories there are:
   `=IF(SUMPRODUCT(($A$2:$A2=A2)*($B$2:$B2=B2))>1,0,1)`
   You can add extra products to this formula to force extra fields to be unique to be counted as well.

SRC:[Simple Pivot Table to Count Unique Values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11876238/simple-pivot-table-to-count-unique-values)

2. Add a Calculated Field in the PivotTable that is:
   `SUM(Duration)/SUM([Helper Column Name])` and include it in the 'Values' section of the PivotTable.  Due to the new column being added, you might have to re-create the PivotTable.

This should produce the average in the manner that you want.