# How can I do a distinct count in a pivot table based on unique values across multiple columns?

Tags: excel, pivot, pivot-table, unique

I have the table below in excel.

**Raw data table**

[image: raw data table]

I need to create a pivot table to count the number of complaints worked on by each unique team member by theme of complaint in the format below. Would really appreciate your help on how this can be achieved :

**Final pivot table format required**

[image: final pivot table format required]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Simple Pivot Table to Count Unique Values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11876238/simple-pivot-table-to-count-unique-values)

Answer (score 0):

I didn't read the whole question, but let me give you this golden trick for counting the amount of distinct values:

Imagine following data:

```
A
A
B
B
B
```

The "count distinct" (2) can be calculated by this formula:

```
=SUM(1/COUNTIF(A1:A5;A1:A5))
```